# How to serve data from jsp to xml?

Tags: xml, jsp

I am asking. how do i make a jsp serve xml data ? or can anyone give me a idea how to do this. from my understanding. this is where the jsp data is converted to xml. ( am i right about this ? ). please correct me if im wrong. thank you

Comment: you may use `jspx` instead of `jsp`, and don't forget to change the default content-type(text/html) to `text/xml`

Comment: ok sir parsa. i will research about this jspx. thank you